# SQL query : Select a thumbnail for a media

Tags: database, post-meta, mysql, gallery, sql

I'm doing a custom gallery for a  portfolio page in a website and It works well if I simply use the URL of the media uploaded this way :

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts AS p INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS m ON p.ID=m.post_id 
WHERE p.post_type='attachment' AND m.meta_key='_wp_attached_file'
```

The thing is, if I upload too many big files, the page gets sloooow. This is why I'd like to use thumbnail but I have no idea how to select them accordingly in the database.
They're created in the wp-content/uploads folder, but I can't see which `meta_key` to select in the database.

Also noticable, my databse doesn't have any `"_thumbnail_id"` in the `meta_key` column.

Anyone has an answer ?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using SQL for this? And not a `WP_Query`? or `get_posts()` or something? Could you maybe include the code that shows what you're doing with the results?

Comment: Jacob, I'm just more comfortable with it, since I have a lot of conditions about whereas a media show up or not, didn't know there was a get posts function.

Comment: All the sizes are stored together in `_wp_attachment_metadata`, but you're going to need to unserialize and handle any missing sizes yourself. It'll be _much_ easier if you use WordPress functions.

Answer (score -1):

```
$Featured_image = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT p.*
      FROM net_5_postmeta AS pm
     INNER JOIN net_5_posts AS p ON pm.meta_value=p.ID 
     WHERE pm.post_id = $da_id
       AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
     ORDER BY p.post_date DESC 
     LIMIT 15
",'ARRAY_A');
```

A related solution, to query for posts WITHOUT providing a post ID (ordered by post date, and using the wp_ database prefix):

```
SELECT
    p1.*,
    wm2.meta_value
FROM 
    wp_posts p1
LEFT JOIN 
    wp_postmeta wm1
    ON (
        wm1.post_id = p1.id 
        AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
        AND wm1.meta_key = "_thumbnail_id"              
    )
LEFT JOIN 
    wp_postmeta wm2
    ON (
        wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id
        AND wm2.meta_key = "_wp_attached_file"
        AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL  
    )
WHERE
    p1.post_status="publish" 
    AND p1.post_type="post"
ORDER BY 
    p1.post_date DESC
```

Comment: This is selecting posts with an attachment, that's not what Gawer wanted. Gawet is asking how to get the URLs for the resized versions of attachments.

Comment: Hi Dharmishtha, unfortunetely, my database doesn't have any "_thumbnail_id" in the meta_key, any idea about the cause ?